# Sharing documents with High volume portal users

Tags: customer-portal, security, licenses, contentdocument, hvpu

My problem is similar to this but also with the added problem of security.
[High Volume Customer Portal user - Insufficient Privileges for non-image Documents](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/265/high-volume-customer-portal-user-insufficient-privileges-for-non-image-documen)

1. I want only a certain group of people (High volume portal users) to be able to see documents.
2. Just like how we have record level security where these portal users can only see records belong to their account, I want them to be able to see the documents that belong to their Account.

Currently like like the issue above, my portal user cannot see the document. I can see it when I am logged in.

Guys I am hoping there is someway we can securely allow this kind of users to view documents. I have looked online and did not get answers.

from comments: I am hoping Salesforce has something for this. This is coming from their framework and so I hope there is something we can do to display attachments/documents to portal users securely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the documents attachments to custom objects owned by the HVCP user and then use Visualforce pages to display the attachments, that should give you the security you need (Document attachments have the visibility of the object they are attached to AFAIK).

Salesforce support can increase the maximum size of attachments on request as well if size is a concern.

Comment: Nice!  There probably aren't too many use cases where multiple unrelated portal users would need access to the same sensitive document; however would this work for multiple users under the same Account wanting access to a single doc?

Comment: Should do if you set the sharing rules right for HVCP and the record is owned by the Account, not the contact.

Comment: I've done a similar approach with attachments and everything worked well.  Adding a scheduled process to clean up the custom objects owned by the HVCP user ensures you don't eat up your storage limits

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. It will definitely give me an alternate means of displaying documents to users.